# Troubleshooting Azure Search poor performance

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am seeing erratic performance with an Azure Search Basic instance. Our index only has 1,544 documents and is 28MB in size, so I would expect searches to be very fast.

Azure Application Insights is reporting 4.7K calls to Azure Search from our app within the last 12 hours, with an average response time of 2.1s and a standard deviation of 35.8s(!).

I am personally seeing erratic performance during my manual testing. A query can take 20+ seconds at one moment, and then just a bit later the same query will take less than 100ms.

There queries are very simple. Here's an example query string:

api-version=2015-02-28&api-key=removed&search=&%24count=true&%24top=10&%24skip=0&searchMode=all&scoringProfile=FieldBoost&%24orderby=sortableTitle

What can I do to further troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 2):

First off, I am assume you have a fairly even distribution of queries which means based on your numbers, you are only ~1 query per second.  Does that sound correct?  If not, and you are seeing large spikes of queries, it is very possible that you do not have enough replicas (copies of the index) to handle the query load. Please note that a single replica Basic service is targeted to handle low single digit QPS (although this can vary widely based on the complexity or simplicity of the queries).  If you go beyond the limits of the service, latency can certainly become an issue.  A good way to drill into this is to use [Azure Search Traffic Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/analyzing-your-azure-search-traffic/) which can expose the search metrics that include data such as the number of queries per second over various timeframe as well as the latency metrics that we are seeing internally.

Also, most importantly, please try to reuse HTTP connections as much as possible and leverage HTTP connection pooling if possible.  By the way, in .NET you should reuse a single HttpClient instance, or SearchIndexClient instance if using our Azure Search SDK.

Comment: Our traffic does vary so it is more concentrated than that. During peak time of 7AM-8AM today there were 2270 calls, which is still less than 1 QPS. The requests are coming directly from our users' browsers, so there is no opportunity to pool connections. Is it possible that the Free tier would provide better performance than Basic? I have turned on analytics to gather more data.

Comment: Yes, it is possible that you would see occasional better performance with free, but you also have to keep in mind that free is a multi-tenant system which means that the usage of other users using free can impact the overall performance of the service.  Basic and Standard are dedicated resources which means that you should see a consistent level of performance.  In fact, as you look at the data from the Search Traffic Analytics and if you are seeing inconsistent performance for a consistent level of traffic that we would want to look into this a lot deeper.

Comment: At this point it looks like a transient issue on Monday morning. I'll leave analytics on going forward and report back if I'm able to capture some actionable data.

Answer (score 0):

I gathered more data and [posted my results](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/b10df4bc-7760-41f3-b222-414fbf1ae473/occasional-poor-search-performance-503-error?forum=azuresearch) over at the Azure Search forum.

The slowdowns are due to the fact that we're running a single basic instance and code deployments by the Azure Search team cause a brief (a few minutes in my experience) interruption / degradation in service.

I find running two basic instances too expensive. Our search traffic doesn't warrant two instances except for availability purposes.

It's my understanding from the forum that the free tier has generally higher availability than a single basic instance. As a result, I have submitted a [feedback item](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/13834863-add-a-paid-shared-option-between-the-free-tier-and) suggesting a paid shared tier that would provide more storage than the free tier while retaining higher availability than a single dedicated instance.